# How to sort files by size on C shell

Tags: shell, unix

How can I get an array of filenames of all files in specified directory sorted by size of file.
For example if I have files with next sizes:

```
file1 58
file2 32
file3 178
```

I want to get something like this:

```
set arr = (file2 file1 file3)
```

Comment: Read the man page for ls, specifically the options for sorting.

Comment: You can read all files arr = (file1 file2 file3 ...) and then order this array using a sorting algorithm like quicksort, heapsort ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can store output as shown in question in a file `sort` and `cut` can work:

```
sort -nk2,2 file | cut -d ' ' -f1
file2
file1
file3
```

and using set directly:

```
set arr = (sort -nk2 * | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works good for me with some modification:
set arr = (`sort -nk2 * | cut -d ' ' -f1`)